# Camera API in Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, media, webcam

Windows provides MediaCapture API to work with web camera in windows store app. But I need to use external API which was provided with camera. It is c++ .dll file. I can't acquire the camera. It looks like the Windows restricts access to camera via external API.

Is it possible to work with web camera via external API instead of native WinRT API in windows store apps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot, the access to the capture device is retricted and you need to use the newest WinRT API for that. 
All the other way of accessing the capture interfaces (webcam, microphone...) are not available. The "old" MediaFoundation API to access the capture device are not available.